# Java code signing certificate issue

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool, code-signing-certificate

I generate a certificate signing request like this:

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore xxxx -dname "CN=www.example.com,OU=Infrastructure and Operations, O=ACME, Inc., L=Test, ST=Test, C=US" && keytool -certreq -alias server -file xxxx.csr -keystore xxxx.jks
```

When a code signing certificate is created, for some reason the CN is set to the organization value instead of the FQDN, that I listed originally `www.example.com`

So the cert has **`CN=ACME, Inc.`**`,OU=Infrastructure and Operations, O=ACME, Inc., L=Test, ST=Test, C=US`

Not sure why it didn't take the FQDN.

Comment: What happens when you omit the whole `O=` part?

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html#DName) say:

> If a distinguished name string value contains a comma, the comma must be escaped by a `"\"` character when you specify the string on a command line, as in
>
> `cn=peter schuster, o=Sun Microsystems\, Inc., o=sun, c=us`

So the valid *dname* is:

```
"CN=www.example.com,OU=Infrastructure and Operations, O=ACME\, Inc., L=Test, ST=Test, C=US"
```

Comment: Yes I did actually escape the comma in the O field. But still the CN ended up with the O value instead of the www.example.com

Comment: Then this may be a bug, I am out of ideas.

Comment: could the issue at the time the certificate is issued and not the CSR itself necessarily? I did verify the information is set properly on the CSR itself.